# How to automate testing reporting dashboards

Tags: automated-tests

I am currently working on a project where we show users their metrics on dashboard and on reporting. QA team is testing it manually like running SQL queries in Database and comparing that number to UI of dashboard. Is there any way to automate this testing?
This application is written in .NET, C#. We dont use any specific reporting tool such as Cognos,....

Comment: What do you want to test (Unit/Integration/UI/API/Performance)?

Comment: I need to test numbers shown on UI with Backend SQL queries result. For example, one of metric for a user is 100% on report UI. i need to make sure that 100% is correct with querying DB. When querying DB i should get 100% in order to consider 100% correct. I hope that make sense.

Comment: Selenium web driver is one option for testing the UI. You've got numerous options for running the SQL including running the raw SQL and entity framework

Answer (score 0):

If the dashboards are web based, you can use tools like QTP or Selenium which supports web application testing. You can also develop a Java based utility for the same if its just the numbers you want to compare. Basically, a framework which connects to the database, runs the reporting query at the backend and compares the numbers with the UI of the dashboard.

If there a way to export the dashboard or reports to excel then you can do an excel to excel comparison of the UI and backend database as well. This should be easier to achieve as compared to data comparison with backend DB.

Answer (score 0):

We are using ARES dashboard(built under Testastra and owned by ZenQ) which is a good test automation dashboard based on just few api calls.
ARES, is an acronym for Test Automation Results dashboard. It's a TestAutomation framework/tool agonistic solution, that simplifies the collection of Test automation results and their analysis via live dashboard, daily/weekly trends, frequent failures etc.
Below are some of the features of ARES:
1. Tool agnostic test automation dashboard
2. SaaS based
3. Shows current live execution and historical test automation insights
4. Free for all

Website: http://www.testastra.com/#ares

Below repo has some code samples, documentation and usage of ARES test automation dashboard:
https://github.com/testastra/ARES

Worth trying.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer